# How to get data after '-' in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How to get data after - in sql server

current i have word something like 059 - Gaffey St.

So my result should be Gaffey St.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is it - letter part and number part:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(50) = '059 - Gaffey Stop.'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@String , CHARINDEX('-' , @String) + 1, LEN(@String)) AS LetterPart, 
CAST(LEFT(@String, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @String+'.') - 1) AS INT) AS NumPart
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like....

```
Declare @String VARCHAR(50) = '059 - Gaffey St.'

Select SUBSTRING(@String , CHARINDEX('-' , @String) + 1, LEN(@String))
```

**Edit**

To only get `59` without the leading zeros

```
Select CAST( LEFT(@String ,  CHARINDEX('-' , @String) - 1 ) AS INT)
```

Comment: and how about just to get result as 59..skipping if 0 is in front

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like:

```
substring('059 - Gaffey St.', charindex('-', '059 - Gaffey St.') + 1, len('059 - Gaffey St.'))
```

You might wish to surround it by ltrim(rtrim(...)) to remove the eventual spaces.